# JQuery Menu in Master Page Reloading in Every Child Page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Jquery SooperFish Menu in my master page.Onclick on any SubMenu option it is reloading the Menu. Is there any way to restict reloading Menu every time in Child Page?
To decrease the Database lookups.

EDIT:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="elogis.master.cs"      Inherits="elogis.elogis" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/sooperfish.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/sooperfish-theme-large.css"    
media="screen"/>
<script src="Jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="Jquery/jquery.easing-sooper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jquery/jquery.sooperfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
    });

</script> 
</head>
<body>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">

 <asp:Literal  ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SooperFish spoorfishMenu = new SooperFish();
        Literal1.Text = spoorfishMenu.ExecuteXSLTransformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code, code, code, buddy. What makes the SooperFish menu to reload the menu? It's simply a jQuery plugin, thus you are in charge of reloading the menu. You can put the menu in a user control, and cache that user control.

Comment: Hi Saeed, Does this added code helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the onClick postback, if you're writing it yourself (JS) add:

> return false;

at the end-

```
onClick="doSomething();return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using `UpatePanel's` or another `AJAX` framework, each `post-back` is a new HTTP request, meaning the menu has to reload because the page is reloaded.

You have several options for caching, search SO or take a look at the link below to get started:

[ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rick,  Firstly am generating the Menu from a dynamic xml like this :<ul class=\"sf-menu\" id=\"nav\"><li><a href=\"#\">MASTERS</a><ul><li><a href=\"#\">ADMINISTRATION</a><ul><li><a href=\"/Pages/Users.aspx\">USERS</a></li><li><a href=\"/Pages/Groups.aspx\">GROUPS</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href=\"#\">ORDERS</a></li><li><a href=\"#\">REPORTS</a></li><li><a href=\"/Pages/Logout.aspx\">LOGOUT</a></li></ul> ... So onclicking any submenu is simply from a anchor tag, Is this happening coz of anchor tag? Am I doing any thing wrong or is there any way to do this better ?